# Show that $E=\mathbb{Q}(a)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $f(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ an irreducible polynomial with the splitting field $E$ and let the group $Gal(E/\mathbb{Q})$ be abelian. If $a$ is a root of $f(x)$ then $E=\mathbb{Q}(a)$.

Could you give me some hints how to show this??

Comment: This is in many ways a duplicate of [this question/answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/668385/11619). Not casting my powervote in this case, but...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $Gal(E|\mathbb{Q}(a))$ is a subgroup of $Gal(E|\mathbb{Q})$. As $Gal(E|\mathbb{Q})$ is Abelian, $Gal(E|\mathbb{Q}(a))$ is a normal subgroup. So, by the fundamental theorem of Galois theory, $\mathbb{Q}(a)/\mathbb{Q}$ is a normal extension. Thus, all roots of the minimal polynomial of $a$, which happens to be $f(x)$ lie in $\mathbb{Q}(a)$. Thus, the splitting field of $f(x)$ is in fact $\mathbb{Q}(a)$ i.e $E = \mathbb{Q}(a)$. Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you explain me why $Gal(E/\mathbb{Q}(a))$ is a subgroup of $Gal(E/\mathbb{Q})$ ??

Comment: Because any automorphism which fixes elements of $\mathbb{Q}(a)$ also fixes elements of $\mathbb{Q}$ as $\mathbb{Q}\subseteq \mathbb{Q}(a)$.

Comment: Do you mean that we have then the following?? 

$$Gal(E/\mathbb{Q}(a))\triangleleft Gal(E/\mathbb{Q}) \Rightarrow \mathbb{Q}(a) \leq \mathbb{Q} \text{ Galois }$$

Comment: Or should it be $\mathbb{Q} \leq \mathbb{Q}(a)$ ??

Comment: No. I mean that as $Gal(E|\mathbb{Q}(a))$ is normal, $\mathbb{Q}(a)/\mathbb{Q}$ is a normal extension. That is the fundamental theorem of Galois theory. $\mathbb{Q}(a)$ is never a subfield of $\mathbb{Q}$. That happens only when $a \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}$ is certainly a subfield of $\mathbb{Q}(a)$. But that is not really an implication of normality of $Gal(E|\mathbb{Q}(a))$.

Comment: Ok!! I understand!! Thank you very much!!! :-)

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: A very nice argument, but this has appeared earlier on the site.