# If the Galois Group of a Field Extension is Abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $f(x)$ be irreducible over a field $k$ characteristic zero, with splitting field $E$, and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be the roots of $f$ in $E$. If the galois group of $E/k$ is abelian prove that $k(\alpha)=k(\beta)$.

Now since the group is abelian the extensions $k(\alpha)$ and $k(\beta)$ are galois and also both have the same degree over $k$. But have can we conclude the statement? Thanks for any help.

Comment: When you say "the" roots, does this imply $\deg f=2$?

Comment: Take a look at [this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/668357/11619). Not sure that it is an exact match, but very closely related.

Comment: Yes, I got the answer from the link, thanks.

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen: No there is no any implication for that.