# Nonabelian Galois Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $f(x)$ be an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ with both real and nonreal roots. Show that its Galois group is nonabelian. Can the condition that $f$ is irreducible be dropped? If not, provide an example to show this.

Comment: Not entirely sure how to do this, but remember the Galois group is a transitive subgroup of $S_n$, $n \geq 3$ which contains a transposition, so that might get you started.

Comment: I'm not quite sure this is true. Take an irreducible polynomial over Q of degree 3, which has a real root and two nonreal roots. Let K be its splitting field. Then [K : Q] = 3 and so the order of the Galois group is 3, so it's abelian. Apologies if I'm missing something.

Comment: I believe such a polynomial would have Galois group $S_3$. If you adjoin the real root, you clearly don't have the complex ones in your extension, so the splitting field is not degree 3.

Comment: @user293121 Thank you, my mistake.

Comment: Just a special case of the argument in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/668385/11619).

Answer (score 2):

For the second part, consider $f(x)=(x^2-2)(x^2+1)$, whose splitting field $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2,i)$ has degree $4$ over $\mathbb Q$.